# How do I read only the bss from size

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to be able to add numbers under data and bss section out of the size information of a file in command line

```
./script.sh [file name]
```

So far I wrote my script as :

```
ExcPath=$1 #read file name from command line
Numberone= size $1 | $data #put data column into Numberone
Numbertwo= size $1 | $bss #put bss column into Numbertwo
sum=$(( $Numberone + $Numbertwo )) # calculate the sum of DATA and BSS
echo $sum
```

`$data` and `$bss` are variables that I assumed that it is how shell reads from column "data" and "bss"

output from `size test`:

```
text   data    bss    dec    hexfile name
2231    600      8   2839      b17   test
```

Expected output after running my script:

```
608
```

How could I achieve this in Shell Script? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: consider reviewing [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then come back and update your question; in particular, provide sample input data, the code you've tried, the (incorrect) output from your code, and the desired (correct) output; also consider validating your syntax @ [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) (hint: your current `DATA = ` and `BSS = ` commands are invalid in `bash`)

Comment: I've corrected my question, please suggest how could I fix my problem.

Comment: where are the variables `$data` and `$bss` coming from and what are their values?

Comment: `Numberone=size $1 | $data` assigns the string `size` to the variable *Numberone*, and then tries to pipe nothing to the value of *data*. This doesn't raise an error, but isn't valid Bash. Printing data in columns is possible, but it's not even clear to me how you're conceptualizing the problem.

Comment: The awk or column utilities are probably what you need, but this question is not really answerable as posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use `awk` for this job:

```
#!/bin/bash

size "$1" | awk 'NR==2{print $2+$3}' # in row 2 sum column 2 and 3
```